# Eiffel: a way to call precursor redefined feature on another function

Tags: eiffel

I'm looking for a way to call `Precursor` on another feature. The context is that I redefine a routine calling another heir's feature that calls mine, and I'd like to call it explicitly. Is there a way to do something such as in java `Precursor.feature_a`.

**If not**, the only alternative I find is to write a `feature_a_implementation` and call it from redefined feature. Is there a particular reason not to have this mechanism? The consequences of doing that would be to define 2 times the contract of `feature_a` into `feature_a` and `feature_a_implementation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feature replication can be used for that:

```
class A feature
    f do print ("A") end
end

class B inherit
    A redefine f select f end
    A rename f as g end
feature
    f do print ("B") end
    h do g end
end
```

Feature `f` of class `A` appears in class `B` twice: under name `f` (the redefined and selected version) and under name `g` (the original version). The feature `h` calls `g` and prints `A` as expected.